# /System is hogging memory and I want to know why. Is it dangerous to use sudo du to investigate?

Tags: macos, memory, spotlight, permission, sudo

`System Information` says that `/System` is holding 80 GB but when I search with `du` I only find 5 GB. I [reset my spotlight memory indexing](https://www.macworld.com/article/2997252/storage/the-case-of-the-missing-el-capitan-hard-disk-space.html) by adding then removing `/` form the "privacy" list in System Preferences -> Spotlight but the discrepancy persists.

[image]

I want to use [this `du` command](https://serverfault.com/a/62422) with `sudo`, but I will only do that if I am absolutely certain that it will not destroy my system. Is it dangerous to use `sudo` with `du`? How can I find what is eating my memory?

```
$  perl -e'%h=map{/.\s/;99**(ord$&&7)-$`,$_}`du -hs /System/*`;die@h{sort%h}'
du: /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.coresymbolicationd: Permission denied
du: /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.receiptInstaller: Permission denied
du: /System/Library/DirectoryServices/DefaultLocalDB/Default: Permission denied





du: /System/Library/User Template: Permission denied
5.2G    /System/Library
$
```

Comment: `du` just reads stuff from disk, so it's not dangerous at all. But the *System* in System Information is not the same as `/System` but rather the whole OS.

Comment: @patrix Thanks! That makes sense. I found the unaccounted for memory with `du -sh /*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /System folder is different to what System Information reports as System usage. There are plenty of other folders, hidden, at the root of a macOS startup disk which add up to many GBs.